# How to generate a unique id from non-unique records in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with 5 columns, none of which are a unique id column.
I want to check if there are any duplicate rows in this table. Currently, I do this with a query like below;

`SELECT conc, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(CAST(col1 AS STRING), 
               CAST(col2 AS STRING), 
               CAST(col3 AS STRING), 
               CAST(col4 AS STRING), 
               CAST(col5 AS STRING)) AS conc 
      FROM <table>)
GROUP BY conc
HAVING total > 1`

Is there an easier way to do this? Because I actually want to do this for a table with dozens of columns.

Comment: Why CONCAT() and not GROUP BY col1,col2,col3?

Comment: Yeah, that's better and I do that most of the time. I guess my question is really is there a way to do group by * instead of writing out all column names?

Comment: You can use numerical column references, which is a bit faster than typing out column names, for example `GROUP BY 1,3,4,5,7,8,9`

Comment: Thanks for that Ben, I didn't know about the numerical column references. Will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to check if there are any duplicate rows in this table

[`TO_JSON_STRING()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string) is useful in such cases

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS row, COUNT(1) AS total
FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t
GROUP BY row
HAVING total > 1
```

> Update

I think using [`Hash Functions`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#hash-functions) can improve performance. For example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  MD5(TO_JSON_STRING(t)) AS id, 
  ANY_VALUE(TO_JSON_STRING(t)) AS row, 
  COUNT(1) AS total
FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t
GROUP BY id
HAVING total > 1
```

Comment: Mikhail - did you make any performance testing to compare this approach with group by?

Comment: @AlexeyMaloletkin - no, i didn't. i would expect it will really depends on many factors (like number of columns, rows even names of columns - short or wide, etc. ) so left it for OP :o)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, worked perfectly. It processed a table with 35 columns (mostly float and integer) and ~1.8 million rows in 25 seconds. Query was 760MB. Group By did the same in 9 seconds, but much less convenient to write.

Comment: great! make sense. thank you for stats. consider voting up if not yet :o)

Comment: @Balkan - see update - would be great to know if this improves performance (based on the same table as stats in your previous comment)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - this updated query took 35.3 seconds.